# Nodejs serverless Windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows-10, serverless-framework

I have a serverless nodejs project which was working just fine. Did not touch it for a week, wanted to re-deploy it and now I'm greeted with the following errors:

1) EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir ‘D:\GIT\awesome.build\node_modules’
2) EEXIST: file already exists, symlink ‘D:\GIT\awesome\node_modules’ -> ‘D:\GIT\awesome.build\node_modules’

First off I get the first error. If I try for a second time I get the second one. If I delete .build I'm back to receiving the first.

I know that during the idle week I did get the spring Windows update.

Windows 10 17134.48
NPM 6.1.0
Nodejs 8.11.1

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Updated Answer***

We've identified and found the issue relating to this. We have published a new NPM module specifically with this fix and created a PR on the original plugin (but he hasn't updated it in ages)

Fixed Version
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hewmen/serverless-plugin-typescript

***Original Answer:***

We're running into the exact same issue. Multiple serverless projects, multiple computers. We've tried different node versions as well. Completely wiping fetched repo and redoing it. We've tried using elevated consoles. No idea what's going on, but we're getting that exact same error on all our stuff across 3 different machines.

Current suspicion is Windows did an update recently that hosed it.. but I figured we'd see more info on it.

However, we did find a workaround for this.

> 1. Delete your current '.build' and '.serverless' folders inside the root project area
> 2. In command prompt, run 'sls package' and let it fail with the same error
> 3. Manually copy over 'node_modules' and 'package.json' from the root directory into the .build folder (delete the ones in there). This won't cause the error saying the .build directory already exists which you might have seen fighting this.
> 4. In command prompt, run 'sls deploy' (or 'sls package' if you only want to package)

Not ideal... but it got us deploying again until we figure out the real issue.

The issue seems to be in the way the symbolic link is created for node_modules inside the '.build' folder. It's linking a directory, but seems to be treating it as a file all of a sudden for whatever reason. In windows if you use "mklink" without the '/D' option on a directory, it will give you the same result we see in the '.build' folder. If you do the mklink /D - you don't have this issue.

This is why our current suspicion is a Windows update. Because everything was working perfectly fine, then all projects across all our Windows PCs stopped. We've rolled back our repos to stuff we've successfully deployed, and no issues. We've attempted to re-deploy projects we haven't touched in months, same issue.

It's very annoying to say the least. I will update this if we find out what's wrong.

Comment: I got angry and tried the Ubuntu on Windows 10 feature, it works most of the time, fails only occasionally :)

Comment: We've created an open issue on serverless's github for this, hopefully we figure out what's wrong.

https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/5013

Comment: We've made some headway, This appears to be a problem specifically with the Typescript plugin for serverless. There is a PR that will fix it, but it's not a good way to fix it. We found a better way to fix it. We will try to get that published as an NPM on Monday and link it to you.

If you want to fix it yourself for the time being, you can go into the serverless-plugin-typescript/dist/src/index.js and look at line 124.

append 'junction' as the last parameter of the fs.symlink and save the file.

I assume Windows updated and made it where this has to be specific now through FS...

Comment: Updated Original Answer

We published a new NPM with the symbolic link fix @MustSeeMelons

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hewmen/serverless-plugin-typescript

Comment: Have you found any proper solution to it? I am still facing this problem.